# Mysql query not executing from script

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I have prepared a script to clear replication logs of Mysql

> mysql -u "$user" -p"$pass" << EOF
>
> > PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE_SUB( NOW( ), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
>
> EOF

The same command works fine when I execute it from Mysql prompt. What is the issue with my script.

Comment: have you tried aligning the `PURGE` line to the left? no leading spaces

Comment: What is the errormessage?

Answer (score 0):

When just passing in a single command it is less error prone to use the `-e ...` option instead of input redirection. One of the many things that can go wrong with redirection is that `TAB` characters in the input stream trigger tab completion which can have undesired and hard to track down results.

So I'd suggest to use

```
mysql -u "$user" -p"$pass" -e "PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE_SUB( NOW( ), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);"
```

instead